# Reuse Specification for different Table as subQuery

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I just started learning the use of `Specification` in Spring queries. I have written a rather complex Specification that filters a database by a type. For demonstration I will show a simple version with the same idea:

```
Specification<Animal> animalWithType(AnimalType type) {
    return (root, cq, cb) -> {
        return cb.equal(root.get(Animal_.type), type);
    };
}
```

I can call it like this `animalRepository.findAll(animalWithType(AnimalType.Dog))` and I get all dogs.

Now I also have humans which have a favourite type of animal. I need to make a query where I get all humans for which we have an animal of their favourite type. For this I want to reuse the first specification, because it is a very complication one. So I want to do something like this:

```
Specification<Human> weHaveFavouriteAnimal() {
    return (root, cq, cb) -> {
        return cb.exists(animalWithType(root.get(Human_.favouriteAnimalType)));
    };
}
```

I cannot do this for two reasons:

- `root.get(Human_.favouriteAnimalType)` will give me `Expression<AnimalType>` which I cannot pass to my `animalWithType` function. I also don't have an easy way to convert a raw AnimalType to `Expression<AnimalType>` and pass it then, because I need an Instance of `QueryBuilder` to do that.
- The function `animalWithType` returns a Specification but I need a Predicate. I assume I need to make a `SubQuery` of some kind here, but I can't pass a `SubQuery` to the function `Specification::toPredicate` because it requires a CriteriaQuery.

Is there a way to reuse a Specification as an "exists" subquery in another Specification for a different Entity?

In SQL the first specification would do something like `select * from animals where type == Dog` and the second one should have this one as a subquery and look something like this `select * from humans where exists (select * from animals where type == humans.favouriteAnimalType)`. My SQL is a bit rusty but I hope this is not too far off. This seems like the first query is very well reused in the second query. I want to do something similar with Specifications.

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061502/spring-data-subquery-within-a-specification

Comment: @Adithya thanks but sadly I can't easily reuse a specification this way because specifications expect criteriaQueries not SubQueries.

Comment: Specification<Human> weHaveFavouriteAnimal() {
    return (root, cq, cb) -> {
 Subquery<Animal> animalSubQuery = cq.subquery(Animal.class);
 Root<Animal> animal = sub.from(Animal.class);
 Expression<Collection<Animal>> favoriteAnimals = animal.get(Human_.favouriteAnimalType);
 ....
    };
}

Comment: @Adithya so you suggest copy and pasting the code instead of reusing it?